# Proof of conservation of the sign of a function

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

The theorem states that: 
If $f(x)$ is continuous in a $\in$ D and $f(a) \ne 0 $ (which is divided in $2$ cases namely $f(a) \lt 0$ and $f(a)\gt0$) than $f(x)$ contains its sign in the neighbourhood of a. I already proved the case of $f(a)\gt0$. 
*To clarify my question I'll also post the case for $f(a)\gt0$

($\forall \epsilon \gt0$) ($\exists\delta\gt0$)($\forall x\in\mathbb R$)($|x-a|\lt\epsilon\Rightarrow(|x-a|\lt\epsilon\Rightarrow f(a) -\epsilon\lt f(x)\lt f(a)+\epsilon)$

Choose for $\epsilon = \frac 12 f(a)\gt0$

Therefore there exists $\delta$ for which the following holds:

$0\lt\frac 12f(a)\lt f(a)\lt\ldots$

To prove: $f(x) \lt 0$ for $|x-a| \lt \delta$

My unfinished proof:

Starting with $\epsilon$-$\delta$ -definition

($\forall \epsilon \gt0$) ($\exists\delta\gt0$)($\forall x\in\mathbb R$)($|x-a|\lt\epsilon\Rightarrow(|x-a|\lt\epsilon\Rightarrow f(a) +\epsilon\lt f(x)\lt f(a)-\epsilon)$

Choose $\epsilon =\frac 12 f(a)\gt 0$

$\Rightarrow\exists\delta: f(x)\lt0\lt\frac 12 f(a)$
$\square\text{Q.E.D.} $

> Is this correct?

PS:

1) I don't know what the translation is of a dutch word to an english word. That's why I translated it litteraly with 'neighbourhood'

2) The last step is probably a mistake because I looked at the graph of a quadratic function where $f(a)\lt0$ where I got stuck while using the $\epsilon$.

Comment: Is this equivalent to the statement of the theorem? "If $f(x)$ is continuous on the set $D$ and at some $a\in D$, $f(a) < 0$, then there exists $\delta$ such that $f(x) < 0$ whenever $|x-a| < \delta$."

Comment: Indeed it's the same

Comment: @eyeballfrog Is this a correct proof?

Comment: The term "neighborhood" is most likely correct. A neighborhood is a set $N_a$ such that there exist an $\epsilon>0$ such that every $x$ such that $0<|x-a|<\epsilon$ is a member of $N_a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof seem to be for the statement that there exists an neighborhood of $a$ such that $f$ have the same sign everywhere in that neighborhood.

The first part of the proof where $f(a)>0$ is correct (this was given by your professor I assume), but the second part has some mistakes.

First of all since $f(a)<0$ you can't chose $\epsilon = f(a)/2$ since that would make $\epsilon$ negative. Instead we should choose $\epsilon = -f(a)/2 = |f(a)/2|$.

Also your instantiation of the definition of continuity is wrong in the end. It should be $f(a)-\epsilon < f(x) < f(a)+\epsilon$ just like in the first case. This leads to $\dots < f(x) < f(a) + |f(a)/2| = f(a)/2 < 0$

The quick solution would be to reuse the first case since $g(x)=-f(x)$ fulfils the requirements of the first case and therefore there is an neighborhood $N$ of $a$ such that $g(x)>0$ there and consequently $f(x) = -g(x)<0$ there.

---

On the other hand if you wanted to prove that if $f\ne 0$ on any interval $D$ then it must have the same sign on the entire interval. You can do that too by using the IVT(*). To see that it needs to be an interval you can use the function $f(x)=\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ and $D=\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ then $f(x)$ is continuous on $D$, but $f(-1) = -1$ and $f(1)=1$.

Using IVT you use proof by contradiction and assume that $f(a) < 0$ yet $f(b)>0$ and since the premisses of the IVT are fulfilled there's an $\xi\in[a,b]$ such that $f(\xi)=0$.

If you don't have the IVT you use the same technique as proving it. Without loss of generality we can assume that $b>a$ and consider the set $M=\{x\in[a,b]: f(x)<0$}. This set is nonempty since $f(a)<0$ and are bounded from above (by $b$), so it has an least upper bound $\xi$. Now we will show that $f(\xi)=0$ by assuming it isn't. For example if $f(\xi)<0$ we would have a neighborhood of $\xi$ such that $f$ is negative there and then $\xi$ wouldn't be an upper bound (OTOH if $f(\xi)>0$ we by the similar method sees that $\xi$ is not the *least* upper bound).

(*) IVT = Intermediate Value Theorem

Comment: My question was part of another question which was divided in $2$ cases: $f(a) \lt 0$ and $f(a)\gt0$. I've edited the first part of my OP.

Comment: Do you mean with IVT the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: This question was mentioned before we even saw that theorem in class.

Comment: @AnonymousI Yes, IVT is the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Can you maybe give a correction of my unfinished proof?

Comment: I've posted the first case that was given by my professor.